# How to access shadow-root (user-agent) from context of a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shadow-root

I've looked at chrome.dom.openOrClosedShadowRoot API (Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/dom/#method-openOrClosedShadowRoot) but that does not seem to work on shadow-root (user-agent). These shadow-root's seem to be browser's implementation for elements such as input, video, etc.

I tried accessing element.shadowRoot and chrome.dom.openOrClosedShadowRoot(element) and was expecting to receive the shadowRoot object, but it always returns null for shadow-root(user-agent).

Answer (score 1):

The only method is to use [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/) API in an extension script like the popup or the background script to send [DOM.getNodeForLocation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#method-getNodeForLocation) with `includeUserAgentShadowDOM` parameter.

Note that using the debugger API will show a warning over all tabs in Chrome.